# Open two forms at startup in c++ builder

Tags: c++, forms, c++builder

I want to open two different forms when running my program. Forms are named Form2 and Form3. Form2 runs normally, but Form3 doesn't. I have put `Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm3), &Form3);` on my project cpp file and `Form3->Show();` in my Unit2.cpp file, but I get error: `"Access violation at address 0047B2CE in module 'Project2.exe'. Read of address 00000384."`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: C++ builder is a pretty old compiler with no development/support since the earlies 2000s. I doubt its even C++98 standard compliant.

Comment: I'm using RAD Studio 2010 so I think its pretty much still supported.

Comment: @Manu343726: C++Builder is still being actively developed. The current version is [C++Builder XE5](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder), with XE6 being released later this year. You are probably thinking of the time when C++Builder was indeed end-of-lifed after C++Builder 6 (in favor of C++BuilderX, which was later abandoned), and did not know that it was revived a few years later in C++Builder 2006 and has been alive ever since, or that it is now owned by Embarcadero, not by Borland anymore.

Comment: @Manu343726: C++Builder does support C++98, and in fact its 64bit compiler supports C++11 as well (its 32bit compiler does not support C++11 yet, but that is in the works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, it is hard to say, but chances are that `Form3` has simply not been created yet when you are calling `Form3->Show()`.  You are getting an error at a memory address close to 0, which is a good indication that you are likely accessing a NULL pointer.

You don't need to call `Show()` unless you want more control over WHEN the Forms are shown.  You could simply set their `Visible` property to true at design-time and let the VCL show them for you when `Application->Run()` is called to start the message loop.

Comment: Yes, it was just like you said, I hadn't noticed that the from wasn't visible.