# Open Form from a loading screen at startup in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I have an application with a MainForm which is a loading screen. This Form is displayed while some stuff are done in the background, such as deciding which form to launch next. I cannot get this to work, I keep having an access violation error.

I got why thanks to this subject : [Open two forms at startup in c++ builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673267/open-two-forms-at-startup-in-c-builder). But the proposed solution is not acceptable for me as I do not know at design time which form will be displayed first.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an application with a MainForm which is a loading screen.

Don't do that.  In VCL, the `MainForm` can't be changed once it is set, and the app will exit when the `MainForm` is closed.  The `MainForm` is set by the first call to `Application->CreateForm()`.  If you want to create Forms before the `MainForm` is created, you must use the `new` operator instead, eg:

```cpp
Application->Initialize();

TLoadingForm *LoadingForm = new TLoadingForm(Application);
LoadingForm->Show();
LoadingForm->Update();

...

Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1); 
...

LoadingForm->Close();
delete LoadingForm;

Application->Run();
...
```

If you want to make decisions about which `TForm` will be the real `MainForm` at runtime, you can do that, eg:

```cpp
Application->Initialize();

TLoadingForm *LoadingForm = new TLoadingForm(Application);
LoadingForm->Show();
LoadingForm->Update();

...

if (someCondition)
    Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1); 
else
    Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2); 
...

LoadingForm->Close();
delete LoadingForm;

Application->Run();
...
```

Be aware, though, that the IDE "owns" the main project source file, and it likely WILL *modify/delete/corrupt your custom code* at some point during your project's development lifetime.  So be *very careful* with custom code you place between the calls to `Application->Initialize()` and `Application->Run()`.  And make sure you have good backups.